# VBA Excel trouble changing layout of plot titles

Tags: vba, fonts, histogram

I have some troubles changing the layout of a histogram.
In my sub the data is generated and a histogram is also plotted by VBA.
I would like to change the layout of the  plot title.
For example the title should read Histogram of *Y*<sub>123</sub>.
But I cannot change the font of "Y" to italic, I only can change the font of the whole title.
When I try to change just the font of "Y"  I get this error.

[image]

Here is a mwe.

```
Sub mwe()
    
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.count <> 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Cells(i + 2, 4) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000)
    Next i

    
    Range("d1:d" & Range("d" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(366, xlHistogram).Select
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Histogram of Y123"
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Font.Italic = True 'works
        .ChartTitle.Characters(14, 1).Font.Italic = True  'does not work
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is trying to format the 1 after the Y as italic.  Is that what you want?  In the VBA IDE put your cursor on the .Characters and press F1.

Comment: Oh you are right this is a typo, nevertheless it does not work.

Comment: You should also be aware that  your code is working on 'Histogram of Y123' and not "Y123".  If this is another typo I'd suggest you close the question and repost when you have code that is correct.

Comment: No, this is correct. Your are right in the end I like to change both, tht title and the axis title, but since both create the same error, I start with changing the plot title and in the following step  will change the axis title.

Comment: I think you would be best served by reducing your code to the SO requirement of the simplest example that demonstrates your problem.